# Clickonce: Published App Installs Local, but fails from website with "Application Validation did not succeed"

Tags: clickonce

This is a recent issue in the last few weeks where my published applications will no longer install from my website.  I can run the setup or the application manifest from my local PC and the installation works.  But from the website, I get the "Application Validation did not succeed" error message.

I've tried the simplest application where I only have a program with a blank form, so it's not related to missing references.  I've tried signed and unsigned.  I tried different Net Framework versions.  I'm running out of things to try. No matter what, it always fails to install from the website, but always installs (with the same published programs) from my local computer.

Answer (score 0):

Got this response from GoDaddy that solved the Problem:
So here the issue was with the firewall cache, so your site has the firewall enabled, I cleared the DNS and the firewall cache and also toggled the php errors and changed the php to 8 then back to the previous one. It might be due to the firewall cache sometimes, so I did the steps which we use to clear cache.

My only issue with this, even though it resolved the problem, is why now?  In all the years I've been doing this, it's the first time firewall cache has been an issue.